# Jquery not detecting Flask session

Tags: python, jquery, flask, session

I am facing a situation where I am able to set a session with Flask and verify the session exists when visiting the Python endpoints directly. When I make my frontend return the session status, the Python endpoint returns not logged in.

Python:

```
@app.route("/status")
def status():
  try:
    session["access_token"]
    result = {
      "rc": "loggedin",
      "msg": f"User is logged in with access token {session['access_token']}."
    }
  except:
    print("No access token found")
    result = {
      "rc": "notloggedin",
      "msg": "User is not logged in."
    }
    
  return jsonify(result)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
  return redirect(OAUTH_URL)

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
  try:
    session.pop("access_token")
    print(f"Ended session.")
  except:
    print("No session to end.")
  return redirect(f"https://{HOME_URL}")

@app.route("/oauth/callback")
def oauth_callback():
  print(REDIRECT_URI)
  code = request.args["code"]
  access_token = client.oauth.get_access_token(
    code, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
  ).access_token
  session["access_token"] = access_token
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  cache: false,
  url: "https://account.mydomain.net/status",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  console.log( msg );
});
```

When calling the Python endpoints directly, it all works. I got to /login, am redirected to the Oauth provider and then returned to my home page. When I then go to /status, it returns:

```
{"msg":"User is logged in with access token REDACTED.","rc":"loggedin"}
```

When the Ajax function calls the endpoint (same browser, same URL as the endpoint I am hitting)

```
{"msg":"User is not logged in.","rc":"notloggedin"}
```

I saw some similar issues, but none that covered this. I expect my Flask session to stay alive, but it does not. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how this works. Don't mind all the print(), this is mostly for debugging this frustrating issue. The Python endpoint is on account.domain.net and the app calling it is on the apex domain.net. CORS is configured properly, since it is returning a value.

I checked both domains, the session cookie is set the same for both.

Comment: Isn't it because you should request the "/login" route first instead of "/status"?

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati /login is visited as a separate page (via a Login button) that immediately redirects to my Oauth provider (Discord) and then redirects back to my main domain. I am able to open a new tab and then visit /status without calling /login beforehand. That's also what's happening in this case. I go to my main page, click login and login through Oauth. The main page then attempts to retrieve that login state, but can't. It appears that the jquery call does not "see" the session that I can see when I go to the Python URL directly.

Comment: If that is the case, I think maybe it is better to change the way you are checking the user login status.

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati Any suggestions? I need my page to check login status when privileged information is accessed. I will try to load more content via Ajax, so not being able to get login-related info from Python is kind of a problem.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know enough about this issue to suggest anything. The only thing that I can think of is to check that the sessions are the same!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get this to work with Jquery, but native JS fetch:

```
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = ".domain.net"
app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"] = "domain-session"
app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN"] = "None"
```

```
async function postData(url = '') {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'include', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```